# duplicate entry org/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionConfiguration$SecurityMode.class

Tags: android-studio, smack, asmack, quickblox-android

I am developing chat application in android.
I have implemented chat feature with smack API and now I am looking for implementing audio video call in my application. 
For that I added Quickblox Sdk in to my project as described in the tutorial.
But when I try to execute my code it gives me error like

```
Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/jivesoftware/smack/ConnectionConfiguration$SecurityMode.class.
```

I have tried to clean my gradle with gradlew clean but that also didn't helped me.

Comment: Change or add multidex property to true in build.gradle file, then try

Comment: @rakesh kalashetti i have already added multiDexEnabled true and dependency compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'.